# filter data in one excel sheet based on data in another excel sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have two excel sheet.

```
Sheet 1 
Dept    Dept ID
X1  1550
X2  1551
X3  1552
X4  1553
X5  1554
X6  1555

Sheet 2 
Dept ID Office
1550    Sydney
1551    Darwin
1552    Melbourne
1553    Perth
1554    Perth
1555    Perth
```

What I want is to filter data on sheet 2 based on selection of Dept in sheet 1.
Suppose I choose Dept X1 than only row in sheet 2 is shown as for Dept_id=1550.

I don't know much about VB script. I tried to use advance filter but couldn't figure it out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is showing a filtered result set the final goal? What do you mean by 'choose x1'? What have you done so far?

Comment: @Jeeped By choose X1 I use filter Dept=X1 in sheet 1. Yea showing filtered result my final goal. I tried few code from google. I dont think they serve my purpose

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you first need to do an INDEX / MATCH formula to match all of the department Id's to Office locations.

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!B1:B7,MATCH(B2,Sheet2!A1:A7,0))
```

That would get everything on one sheet. It's easy to match 6 examples here but I'm assuming you need help with hundreds or thousands of lines, in which case you would autofill the formula down the column:

[image: Link 1]

Here's what 'Sheet2' looks like per your example data:

[image: Link 2]

Now that you've got everything on one page you can just filter it normally:

[image: Link 4]

Pick only the data you want:

[image: Link 3]

Hope that helps!

Comment: I dont want the data to be on same page.Filter of first excel(sheet) is applied to other excel(sheet) automatically .